# I built a Facebook Marketplace web scraper in selenium but having issues with remote hosting

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-scraping

The scraper runs fine locally, it gets search results just fine. Problem is that Facebook requires logging in to do this. The bot logs in without issues locally but when running from remote hosting facebook detect this as a suspicious login and starts asking questions. Any ideas on how to get by this?

Or was my initial approach the issue?

Comment: Facebook knows which IPs you've logged in from. It makes sense, from a security perspective, to scrutinize login attempts from new IP addresses.

Comment: Note that web sites typically do not want you to scrape them. You can expect further difficulties, including account bans.